# Use of Augmenter in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Does anyone explain me why we need Augmenter in selenium? What does it mean? What's it use?
I have seen many forum's explaining the use of augmenter for capturing screenshots or rotating mobile screen.

Comment: Earlier for taking screenshot it was used cause RemoteWebDriver did not implements TakeScreenshot interface. But in newer versions of webdriver, it does. And the reason for this class u can see [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/Augmenter.html) accompanied by a note.

Comment: There's not much documentation available about Augmenter class except the examples you may have already seen.

Answer (score 4):

RemoteWebDriver does not implement the TakesScreenshot class if the driver does have the Capabilities to take a screenshot then Augmenter will add the TakesScreenshot methods to the instance http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp